# Exclude line when value is met

Tags: sql

I need to filter my results so that I only have production orders where the `JOBSTATUS` is 'WAITING' or 'STARTED'.  I don't want any other types of job statuses. So, for example, if the production order has a job with a job status of ENDED, I want to exclude that production order from the results.

```
PT.PRODID (Production Order)
PT.JOBNUM (JOB NUMBER)
PRJ.JOBID (Job Identification)
PRJ.JOBSTATUS (Job Status)

Status: 

0 - Coming
1 - Waiting
2 - Started
4 - Ended
```

As I mentioned, I have all the data I need but I don't know how to filter it further.

My attempts have done nothing more than filter out job statuses that have ENDED.  I want to exclude any production order that has a job status of ENDED.

So my results should look like this:

```
PT.PRODID    PT.Jobnum        PRJ.JOBID        PRJ.JOBSTATUS
ABC            10               9876               WAITING
ABC            20               5432               STARTED
ABC            30               1098               WAITING
ABC            40               7654               WAITING
ABC            50               3210               STARTED
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT
         PRJ.PRODID 'Prod #'
        ,PRJ.OprNum 'Oper #'
        ,PRJ.JOBID 'Job #'
        ,PRJ.WRKCTRID 'Resource'
        -- Assign JOBSTATUS int to String value
            ,(Case PRJ.JOBSTATUS
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Waiting'
                WHEN '2' THEN 'Coming'
                WHEN '3' THEN 'Started'
                WHEN '4' THEN 'Ended'
                Else 'No Data'
                END) 'JobStatus'
        ,PRJ.FROMDATE 

FROM
    PRODROUTEJOB AS PRJ
        JOIN PRODTABLE AS PT ON PRJ.PRODID = PT.PRODID

        WHERE PT.PRODSTATUS = '4'--Show only Production orders that are STARTED
                AND PRJ.JOBTYPE = '2' -- Filter only for jobs that are PROCESS and not QUEUE BEFORE
```

The results I need are production orders `PT.PRODID` that don't have job statuses `PRJ.JOBID` of (4)-ENDED or (1)-COMING.  If the job status has either of those statuses, then exclude the production number and all job status lines from the results.

Comment: You've tagged 3 different databases, which are you actually using? Can you also add the query you've got so far?

Comment: `select ..... where PRJ.JOBSTATUS <> 'ENDED'`

Comment: I suggest learning the fundamentals of sql before attempting to use it. To that end, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in Ten Minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what your final query should look like, but a `HAVING` clause can be used to filter based on an aggregate:

```
SELECT JOBID 
FROM Projects
GROUP BY JOBID 
HAVING MAX(Status) < 4
```

I'm assuming you have multiple rows per job, with different status values, so aggregating will allow you to filter down to the jobs for which a specific status is never present across rows.

If the `Status` isn't actually `4` but `Ended` then you can use a conditional aggregate in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT JOBID 
FROM Projects
GROUP BY JOBID 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Ended' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Hart CO, I tried the HAVING command but it filters out anything with the status of 4.  That's partially correct.  If there is any status of 4 then I want to remove all lines, regardless of the status, and production order from my results.